# postgres transform 2 columns as json with array

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have next resultset from Postgres data base :
actually I never work with postgres json and I naven't found any same examples

```
id | another_id
--------------
1  | 10
1  | 11
3  | 20
3  | 21
3  | 22
```

and I need to transform it as a json string:

```
{"id":1 , "another_id" : {[10,11]}}
{"id":3 , "another_id" : {[20,21,22]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

example with `to_json`

```
x=# select to_json(s)
from (
  select id,array_agg(another_id) another_id
  from s1
  group by id
) s;
             to_json
----------------------------------
 {"id":1,"another_id":[10,11]}
 {"id":3,"another_id":[20,21,22]}
(2 rows)
```

Mind In my example instead of `{[10,11]}` I get `[10,11]` which would be syntactically correct for json

Answer (score 2):

You need to combine json aggregation with building json objects:

```
select json_build_object('id', id, 'another_id', json_agg(another_id))
from the_table
group by id;
```

http://rextester.com/BCK50498